# Mysql Updating a record with a value from the previous record

Tags: mysql

I have the following table, and what I'm trying to do is to update, for example, RefIDs 3-14 with the same Status value "Added" as the previous value.  I want to do this until it reaches the next completed value.  So when it encounters "Added", it updates all rows below that have a null with "Added" until it reaches the next RefID that has a populated Status, and subsequently updates the next batch of values.  Can this be done?  Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm looking for this to be dynamic, as I don't want to manually update, say, Status = "Added" where RefID is 3.

`RefID        Status

1               Null

2               Added

3               Null

4               Null

5               Changed

6               Null

7               Null`

What I want to achieve is this:

`RefID           Status

1               Null

2               Added

3               Added

4               Added

5               Changed

6               Changed

7               Changed`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this query -

```
UPDATE refs_table t1
  JOIN (
    SELECT RefID, @s:=IF(Status IS NULL, @s, Status) Status
      FROM (SELECT * FROM refs_table ORDER BY RefID) r,
    (SELECT @s:=NULL) t
  ) t2
  ON t1.RefID = t2.RefID
SET t1.Status = t2.Status
```

Comment: Works fantastically.  Thank you very much.  I was looking for a way to avoid using a cursor.

Comment: An explanation of what's going on in earch sub-statement would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE
    TableX AS t
JOIN
    TableX AS tu
ON tu.RefID = (
    SELECT 
        MAX(prev.RefID)
    FROM 
        TableX AS prev
    WHERE 
        prev.RefID < t.RefID AND 
        prev.Status IS NOT NULL) 
SET
    t.Status = tu.Status
WHERE
    t.Status IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a cursor.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html

EDIT: Okay, okay, I read the other answers. Way better. Cursor is overkill here.